# Google Site and WordPress

Tags: hosting

Can WordPress be used through Google Sites? Instead of creating a blog at WordPress itself, I'm considering to make a mesh of a website and blog using Google Sites and WordPress source code, but I'm not sure how to do this, or even if it's possible.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Google Sites does not have databases sorry you have to use another site.

Also becuase I don't think they have PHP on them.

Comment: What feature of WordPress relies on database?

Comment: @Oxwivi all of it. To store the posts, plug-ins, pges, etc.

Comment: Ugh, my ambitions are crushed! My primary reason for Google Sites was that Google offers services to organizations, so I could've created a collaborative group easily with personalized emails and such...

Comment: @Oxwivi sign up to freehostingcloud.com and get the free hosting package and then sign up for the Free Version of Google Apps.

Comment: @Oxwivi go to http://co.cc/ for a free domain name.

Comment: @Benny, how do I sign up for it?

Comment: @Oxwivi type a domain name and then choose it and then down the bottom choose create account.

Comment: @Benny, Will it work with any hosts?

Comment: @Oxwivi yeah just find the DNS records for the host and type it in co.cc

Comment: @Benny, thanks for all the info, now the last question, will it let me use WordPress with Google Apps management?

Comment: @Oxwivi yes but you can't sinatll it thow Google Sites.

Comment: @Benny, I can't install it through Google Sites you mean?

Comment: @Oxwivi yes but though freehostingcloud.com you can install it in one click.

Comment: @Oxivi ok upvote my other posts?

Comment: @Benny, I can't seem to figure out how to let Free Hosting Cloud take control of it, now that I registered a `.co.cc` domain. Any pointers? And I'll upvote your other posts as you requested.